# I need to know the task number of each result from R parallel socket cluster

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a problem using the R parallel socket cluster , and  the function foreach to identify which result came from which task.

Imagine the following code:

```
require(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)
raffle <- foreach(i = 1:10, .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
    Sys.sleep(0.2 + exp(-3 + rnorm(1,0,0.5)))
    sample(1:60, 6, replace = FALSE)
}
stopCluster(cl)
raffle
          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
result.1    45   28   15   41   21   56
result.2    44   22   32   40   17   26
result.3    28   30    1    4   24   20
result.4     7   60   20    1   40   23
result.5    44   16    5   53   20   31
result.6    35   29   26   15   11   12
result.7    21   12   48   32   36   58
result.8    25    8   34   57   55    6
result.9     1    2   17   33   53   45
result.10   37   36   40   33    6   10
```

I can't know from which task came the result.8 because of the random time variable.

Does anyone know how I can get that info?

Answer (score 1):

When using the `doParallel` backend with a socket cluster (as in your example), the tasks are computed using the `clusterApplyLB` function. This allows for load balancing, but it still always returns the results in order, so you know that the rows of the resulting matrix will be ordered by task ID.

There are `foreach` parallel backends that do allow the results to be combined out of order, but the results are always combined in order unless you specify the `foreach` `.inorder=FALSE` option. In that case, you could include a task ID in the result. In your example, you could use:

```
r <- foreach(i = 1:10, .combine = rbind, .inorder=FALSE) %dopar% {
    Sys.sleep(0.2 + exp(-3 + rnorm(1,0,0.5)))
    c(i, sample(1:60, 6, replace = FALSE))
}
tasks <- r[,1]
raffle <- r[,-1]
```

In a more complicated example, you could return the task ID and result in a list, and then use a custom combine function to handle the task ID. But as I said, this isn't technically necessary when using the `doParallel` backend.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I tought of a way to get the completion order also.

```
require(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)
r <- foreach(i = 1:10, .combine = rbind, .inorder = FALSE, .final = data.frame) %dopar% {
    Sys.sleep(0.2 + 10 / i)
    c(i, format(Sys.time(), '%H%M%OS6'), sample(1:60, 6, replace = FALSE))
}
stopCluster(cl)
r <- r[order(r[, 2]), ]
r[, 2] <- 1:nrow(r)
names(r) <- c('taskID', 'completionOrder', 1:6)
r
```